# Google login with flutter aad_oauth does not work because of webview

Tags: flutter, azure, authentication, google-signin

I am doing an azure active directory login with this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/aad_oauth.

However the plugin uses the webview plugin and the following error occurs because of that.

```
“You can’t sign in from this screen because this app doesn’t comply with Google’s secure browser policy”
Error 403 dissallowed_useragent
```

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Google allows sign-in with Google Account only in normal browsers, it restricts it in web-views due to security reasons and recommends Google SDKs for iOS and Android for this purpose.

A similar behaviour exists for Facebook login.

In general, these services recognize the default WebView user agent, so to make it work, you could just set a custom user agent value.

You can use my [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin to implement this logic.

I have created a project example that implements it and it's available at https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/third_party_oauth_user_sign_in

[image: Android example]
[image: iOS example]

Comment: Does Apple/Google reject the apps with modified User Agent?